# Creat IIS USER in SQL from different machine

Tags: iis, sql-server

I am trying to create a IIS APPPOOL\poolName security login in SQL but getting this error "Windows NT user or group 'IIS APPPOOL\poolName' not found." I am doing this to run elmah.
doing this from different machine please post any solution stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security! Your question needs more details. What is the exact cmd are you running? Are you using xp_cmdshell or the host cmd? What level of permission do you have on the host running IIS? What install doc are you working from? The more details you can provide, the higher the quality of answers.

Comment: Is your DB server in the same windows domain as the webserver? If not, those usernames will mean nothing at the DB end. Password auth?

Answer (score 0):

The app pool identity allows you to access network resources using the machine account, so instead of granting the app pool access to the SQL Server by name, you simply need to grant access to the web server machine account, which looks like this:  `DOMAIN\web-server-name$' Note the`$` at the end, which is always there to denote a machine account.

Answer (score -1):

You generally want to use either a local user or domain user for your App Pools. Let's give an example machine/domain name:

**Domain:**

Example.com\ServiceUser

**Machine:**

TestBox\ServiceUser

It doesn't have to be prefaced with "apppool". Once the user shows up in the user dialog of the box, whether local group, or domain, it should be able to be added to SQL Server.